# \(\(f(x)\)\) double \('s problem

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Here is one problem I encountered with in Converting Mathematica Notebook to TeX:
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25928/save-as-tex-fx-double-s-problem

And I got some double `\(`'s

```
\(\(f(x)\)\)
```

Is this a problem of Mathematica?
I do not know where else would generate some similar `\(`s

And, if I cannot control Mathematica to generate single `\(`,
how to change the `\(\(` to `\(` conveniently ?

I sometimes use Find/Replace to remove that redundant `\(` in WinEdt

[image]

Comment: @percusse Is it possible to compile two `\(\(`'s \(\(f(x)\(\( without errors, in (for example) WinEdt?

Comment: Although it is *possible*, it is not a good idea.  It would be a much better plan to figure out what is causing those double `\(`s and fix that.  It will make your life *sooo* much easier!

Comment: I am not on the other site, but in your mathematica set-up it does not make much sense to say that inline should be rendered as DisplayFormula.  My guess is the converter used to output `$...$` for inline math and `$$...$$` for display.  Now `\(...\)` is often to be preferred for inline, but the dispaly equivalent is `\[...\]` not `\(\(...\)\)`.

Comment: @AndrewSwann aha, something similar, good point.  Maybe that's the answer.

Comment: Can you explain that Mathematica code?  I have Mathematica on my computer and when I enter in integrals, derivatives, summations, limits, etc.  I don't have any issues whereas you are specifying inline, row box, etc.  Have you tried just entering in your `f[x] := equation` without all that and converting to `LaTeX`?

Comment: I feel like this is a [Mathematica question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/) rather than a LaTeX one.

Comment: @dustin there are two methods in Mathematica to convert formula into Tex, one is use to use function `TeXForm`, another is save notebook as .Tex file. My example is for the second one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can change the definition of `\(` and `\)` so that they check whether they are followed by another occurrence of themselve and `\@gobble` that.

These leave the math-shifts `$` and `$$` as they are, meaning that LaTeX’s superior `\[`/`\]` will be used.

Though, it would be better to fix Mathematica’s bug …

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\let\orig@mo\(
\let\orig@mc\)

% (choose one)
% \(\( = display style
\def\({\kernel@ifnextchar\({\expandafter\[\@gobble}\orig@mo}
\def\){\kernel@ifnextchar\){\expandafter\]\@gobble}\orig@mc}

% \(\( = inline math
\def\({\kernel@ifnextchar\({\expandafter\orig@mo\@gobble}\orig@mo}
\def\){\kernel@ifnextchar\){\expandafter\orig@mc\@gobble}\orig@mc}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
inline $ \frac {x^2}{y} $

display $$ \frac {x^2}{y} $$

inline \( \frac {x^2}{y} \)

display \(\( \frac {x^2}{y} \)\)
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Almost certainly this is a badly configured conversion wher einline math has changed from `$` to `\(` which has had an accidental effect where `$$` has changed to `\(\(`.

Fixing the convertor would be best but if you go

```
\let\($  \let\)$
```

Then `\(` will act like `$` and

```
aaa\(a=b\)bbbbaaa\(\(c=d\)\)bbbb
```

will work like

```
aaa$a=b$bbbbaaa$$c=d$$bbbb
```

with a=b in inline math annd c=d in display math.